# Telnet doesn't accept Enter as a newline

Tags: windows, telnet

I am just trying some *really* basic Telnet as part of a HTTP tutorial, but everything I've read assumes that the Enter key works very differently than how it's been working for me so far.

So an example like:

```
>telnet
Microsoft Telnet>o www.bing.com 80
Connecting To www.bing.com...
Microsoft Telnet>GET / HTTP/1.1 [ENTER]
Host: www.bing.com [ENTER]
[ENTER]
```

Doesn't work at all for me because as soon as I press `Enter` key the **first** time, I immediately get

```
Invalid Command. type /?help for help
```

So I never even get the chance to complete the `GET` command.

I've tried having `set crlf` turned on and off, and that doesn't make a difference. Tried using Ctrl/Shift/Alt-Enter to get it to put in a newline instead of submitting the command, and no luck.

I've googled around a lot, and every tutorial / forum / etc. just assumes that the Enter key puts a LF or CRLF in and that you have to hit Enter twice to submit the command; I haven't found anything that addresses what to do if that is not the case.

I'm on Windows 7, with Telnet Client featured turned on, in a regular Command Prompt.

Comment: It'll work fine if you do `telnet <ip> <port>`

Comment: @gparent No, that hasn't made any difference for me.

Comment: Weird, my bad. Usually works fine for me. Good luck!

Comment: Also: Apologies for the off topic question --- it looks like this would have been more appropriate for superuser.com than serverfault. My bad!

Comment: @east-of-nowhere From the C:\> command prompt type `telnet www.bing.com 80` then enter, then press ctrl-], and you will see the Microsoft Telnet> prompt, and press enter again to get into echo mode. Now you can type in `GET / HTTP/1.1` or multiple lines (get and headers). Press ctrl-enter when you have finished, or press enter on a blank line (that last feature  means you can't enter a blank line - since telnet is not really designed for this purpose). To install telnet from a command line on Win-7 (as admin) from C:\> use `pkgmgr /iu:"TelnetClient"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were in command mode. Thus you were sending those commands to the telnet client, not to the open connection to the remote host.

To switch back to the open connection, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> (alone) at the telnet prompt. (And press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> to switch back to command mode.)

Comment: That got some progress: pressing `Enter` like that does allow me to put in `Microsoft Telnet>GET / HTTP/1.1 [ENTER]
Host: www.bing.com [ENTER]`
and it must be sending the GET request after all because I'm getting a HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request for every URL I try. I don't know if that's a problem with the telnet command I'm trying or if most web servers nowadays just reject telnet on principle, though...

Comment: Press Enter _first_, before you send the `GET`.

Comment: Still a Bad Request. But at least telnet is definitely sending something to the server!

Comment: Update - the Bad Request bit seemed to have something to do with me being behind a proxy at the time -- I tried all those steps on a different workstation later and finally got HTTP 200.